# Viewing html file on local network

Tags: windows, networking

As title says, I have html file, which I would like to allow access with some IPs on my Wi-Fi. 
I changed my hosts file.

```
192.168.0.162   Ntb
```

I also needed to add exception to firewall.
Now I can ping this IP.
But how can I show this user with this IP adress my html file?
Which is located:

```
C:\Users\patri\Desktop\bc4\f_end\login.html
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: Either you need to make your folder `C:\Users\patri\Desktop\bc4\f_end` a Windows share if you want the user to access the HTML file as a file from their browser just as a file, or you need to start up an HTTP server on your computer if you want them to access it using HTTP.

Comment: and can I create http server which would be only accessible for Ip adresses on that WiFi network?

Comment: You can configure your server to restrict access. You'll need to check the documentation for the particular HTTP server software you are using to determine how that's done.